# Make an array of months and years based on user selected date 'From' and 'To'

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Request will be like this:

```
$request->monthFrom = "12"; 
$request->yearFrom = "2016";
$request->monthTo = "5";
$request->yearTo = "2017";
```

I want to make an array having all months and years from user selected data values.

```
array[
0 => "year" = "2016"
     "month" = "12"
1 => "year" = "2017"
     "month" = "1"
2 => "year" = "2017"
     "month" = "2"
3 => "year" = "2017"
     "month" = "3"
4 => "year" = "2017"
     "month" = "4"
5 => "year" = "2017"
     "month" = "5"
]
```

Comment: So.. u want an array like this,  an array like this, an array like this ? Then try to do it, if u can't, show us what u tried and then we can help u.

Comment: use array_push()

Comment: You want what? Where is the request, and what is the result format? Where did the data on 2017 3 come from? Where is your code?

Comment: Pls be specific.What exactly your requirement?

Comment: Use looping structure and datetime functions in PHP. Come up with your code, we will help you complete

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used for loop to achieve this.

```
    $mlist = array();
    $m1 = 11;        $y1 = 2015;        $m2 = 3;        $y2 = 2016;
    $diff = (($y2 - $y1) * 12) + ($m2 - $m1);

    for($i=0;$i<=$diff;$i++){
        $mlist[] = array('month'=>$m1,'year'=>$y1);
        $m1++;
        if($m1 > 12){
            $m1 = $m1-12;
            $y1++;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mlist);
    echo "</pre>";
```