# PHP Generate Array with number of month and year display based on user selected

Tags: php, arrays

I have four request of the form:

> Month_From : 11
>   Year_From : 2015
>   Month_To : 3
>   Year_To : 2016

Now I need to generate an array having all the months and years from the user selected data values:

```
Array (
[0] = Array(
   'month'   => '11'
   'year'    => '2015'
 );
[1] = Array(
   'month'   => '12'
   'year'    => '2015'
 );

[2] = Array(
   'month'   => '1'
   'year'    => '2016'
 );

[3] = Array(
   'month'   => '2'
   'year'    => '2016'
 );
[4] = Array(
   'month'   => '3'
   'year'    => '2016'
 );
);
```

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49549095/5447994. Please try yourself and then post your code here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi try using the below code. I have iterated over the whole time frame and used each month to create an array.

```
$start    = (new DateTime('2015-11-01'))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime('2016-03-01'))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$data = array();

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $data_month = array(
        'month' => $dt->format("m"),
        'year' => $dt->format("Y")
  );
  array_push($data, $data_month);
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 `while` loops, like:

```
$Month_From = 11;
$Year_From = 2015;
$Month_To = 3;
$Year_To = 2016;

$result = array();
$tMonth = $Month_From;
$tYear = $Year_From;

while( $tYear <= $Year_To ) {
    while( ( $tMonth <= 12 && $tYear < $Year_To ) || ( $tMonth <= $Month_To && $tYear == $Year_To ) ) {
        $result[] = array(
            "month" => $tMonth,
            "year" => $tYear,
        );
        $tMonth++;
    }

    $tMonth = 1;
    $tYear++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => 11
            [year] => 2015
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => 12
            [year] => 2015
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => 1
            [year] => 2016
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => 2
            [year] => 2016
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => 3
            [year] => 2016
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build date based on date input.

I am not giving you exact code. But just to have an hint how to archive soluion.

```
$start_date = sprintf('%s-%s-1', $start_year, $start_month);

$end_date = sprintf('%s-%s-1', $end_year, $end_month);


while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {

    $next_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first day of next month", strtotime($date)));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this using for loop.

```
    $m1 = 11;        $y1 = 2015;        $m2 = 3;        $y2 = 2016;

    $mlist = array();
    $diff = (($y2 - $y1) * 12) + ($m2 - $m1);

    for($i=0;$i<=$diff;$i++){
        $mlist[] = array('month'=>$m1,'year'=>$y1);
        $m1++;
        if($m1 > 12){
            $m1 = $m1-12;
            $y1++;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mlist);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only array function range

```
//months 1-12

$fromMonth = 11;
$fromYear = 2015;
$toMonth = 3;
$toYear = 2016;

$years = range($fromYear, $toYear);
foreach($years as $year) {

  $months = range(1, 12);

  if($year==$fromYear) {
    $months = range($fromMonth, 12);
  }
  elseif($year==$toYear) {
    $months = range(1, $toMonth);
  }

  foreach($months as $month) {
    $ret[] = [
        'year' => $year,
        'month' => $month,
    ];
  }
}
```